# Angular custom validation

Tags: angular, validation

I have the registration form with the `password` and `confirm_password` fields. And I have the custom validation to check that these passwords are the same. The thing is: when I'm typing 'qwerty123' in the `password` field and `qwerty123` in the `password_confirm` field everything is fine. But if I then add some char, for example, `4` in the `confirm_password` field and then add the same char `4` to the `password` field my form won't be valid (property `valid` is `false`) and I can not do anything with it.

I looked at the similar solution here, but the things that were helpful there are not helpful for me.

My component:

```
  public userNameInput: FormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.minLength(this.limits['username'][0]),
    Validators.maxLength(this.limits['username'][1])
  ]);
  public emailInput: FormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    RegisterFormComponent.checkEmail
  ]);
  public passwordInput: FormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(this.limits['password'][0]),
    Validators.maxLength(this.limits['password'][1]),
    RegisterFormComponent.checkPasswordsMatching
  ]);
  public confirmPasswordInput: FormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    RegisterFormComponent.checkPasswordsMatching
  ]);

  public registrationForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    userName: this.userNameInput,
    email: this.emailInput,
    password: this.passwordInput,
    confirmPassword: this.confirmPasswordInput
  });

  private static checkPasswordsMatching(input: FormControl): null | { [ key: string ]: boolean } {
    if (!input.root || !input.root.get('password')) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      (
        input.root.get('password').value === '' ||
        input.root.get('confirmPassword').value === ''
      )
      ||
      input.root.get('password').value === 
      input.root.get('confirmPassword').value
    )
      ? null
      : { mismatched: true };
  }
```

My HTML from the template:

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="username"
  id="username"
  [formControl]="userNameInput"
  [class.error]="
    userNameInput.hasError('minlength') || 
    userNameInput.hasError('maxlength')
  "
>
<input
  id="email"
  type="text"
  name="email"
  [formControl]="emailInput"
  [class.error]="
    !emailInput.pristine &&
     emailInput.hasError('invalid')
  "
>
<input
  type="password"
  name="password"
  id="password"
  [formControl]="passwordInput"
  [class.error]="
    passwordInput.hasError('minlength') ||
    passwordInput.hasError('maxlength') ||
    confirmPasswordInput.hasError('mismatched')
  "
>
<input
  type="password"
  name="password_confirm"
  id="password_confirm"
  [formControl]="confirmPasswordInput"
  [class.error]="
    passwordInput.hasError('mismatched') ||
    confirmPasswordInput.hasError('mismatched')
  "
>
<button
    [disabled]="!registrationForm.valid"
>Confirm</button>
```

Comment: did you check which error are you getting? might be that the 'password' field  is just too long? cause you have validation for max length there, but not for 'confirmPasswordInput'

Comment: Nope, it's the 'mismatched' error, it's not about the length for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because angular doesn't rerun validators on other input, just on the one user is currently typing in. You can rerun validators on the other input with `updateValueAndValidity`.

Comment: Yes, I found out the whole picture.
1. As you said, Angular doesn't update the validators, I need to do it manually (but sometimes it does, don't know why).
2. Important - I need to use FormGroup to group my 2 password inputs and set the matching validator to this group. This passwords group should be the group of the main form FormGroup.
More details I found here, it was helpful:
https://bertrandg.github.io/angular2-forms-form-group-validation/ 
Good luck to everyone who will get the same issue.